# How to do a find query on the result of another find query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.6

I'm working with MongoDB because the company where I work is doing a migration from pSQL. We have reports with filters: first the report lets you select a range of dates by year and month, then you can add filters by date/hour (in the range previously selected) or another fields. The problem is how to query the first the range of dates and then the secondary filters to get the results?

For example, this is the range to display the data:

```
db.report.find(
    {
        Fecha:{
            $gte: ISODate("2018-08-01T00:00:00Z"),             
            $lte: ISODate("2018-08-31T23:59:59Z")
        }
    }
)
```

After this first filter, I need to filter again with `$gte: ISODate("2018-08-02T11:00:00Z")` and `$lte: ISODate("2018-08-02T12:00:00Z")`

as well as other filters, but the main problem is the date filter.

Mongo Version: 3.6 and we use Python 2.7 on the backend.